# How to pass bash variable to php

Tags: php, bash, laravel-5

I'm trying to connect to a server using SSH in Laravel 5.2, sometimes it could be correct, sometimes the credentials might be false.

So far I'm trying something like this, but if I give wrong credentials it is giving an error page, instead I would like to know at which command it fails, and would like to show the output of the failed command.

So far here is the code I'm trying,

```
try {
                SSH::into('production')->run([
                    "if [ -d 'test' ]; then
                        cd public_html/
                        touch laber.txt
                        echo $key >> laber.txt
                        chmod 0444 laber.txt
                     else 
                        MOREF='Could not find a test directory'
                     fi"
                 ]);
                 $var = getenv("MOREF");
                 print_r($var);
                 die;
}
           catch (\Exception $e) {
              return $e;
              //return Response::json(array('error' => 'Website credentials are wrong'));
           }
```

I'm trying to access MOREF variable but Im not getting the value in PHP, also I would like to know from the above set of commands inside if loop, which commands fail, and how do I output that this particular command has been failed...

Comment: Is the variable set in the shell? Did you double check it?

Comment: Also try $_SERVER['MOREF'];